# OleDb regular expression

Tags: regex, excel, oledb

What I am trying to do is select all rows which have years beginning with 19 or 20, i.e.1997 or 2010, the other criteria works ok i.e.MY%. I have used this [F1] like '%19%' or [F1] like '%20%' but it's not ideal as it picks up things like L319. I was wondering if anyone knows of a better way to do this ?

OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select [F1],[F3],[F4],[f5] From [Sheet1$] where [F1] like 'MY%' or [F1] like '%19%' or [F1] like '%20%' and (([F3] <> '') and ([F3] <> 'TBC'))", conn);

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove the leading `%` sign:

```
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select [F1],[F3],[F4],[f5] From 
[Sheet1$] where [F1] like 'MY%' or [F1] like '19%' or [F1] like '20%' and     
(([F3] <> '') and ([F3] <> 'TBC'))", conn);
```

Comment: MY10  SAJAC16P3ALV03318 Yes  1
MY13  SAJAC1685D8V39964 Yes  1
MY16 TBC TBC TBC  1
X400     
Blank line                                               OleDbDataAdapter("Select [F1],[F3],[F4],[F5],[F6] From [Sheet1$] where [F1] like 'MY%' or [F1] like '19%' or [F1] like '20%'  and ([F3] <> '' and [F3] not like '*TBC*')", conn); It's selecting the row with TBC which I dond won't ?

Answer (score 0):

The `YEAR` function should be available to you. Here are a couple of examples.

```
... WHERE YEAR([F1])>1899 AND [F3] <> '' AND [F3] <> 'TBC';
```

... or,

```
... WHERE RIGHT(YEAR([F1]), 2) IN ('19', '20') AND [F3] <> '' AND [F3] <> 'TBC';
```

I don't completely understand how something like *L319* would come into that. Perhaps you can edit your question to include sample data if you need further assistance.